# Data Science book with exercices

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, books

I'm looking for a data science book that covers statistics, probabilities, machine learning, and includes exercises for practice. I believe that having exercises will greatly help in understanding and applying the concepts.

Can anyone recommend a book that covers:

1. Basics of statistics and probabilities
2. Different machine learning algorithms
3. Real-world applications Exercises with solutions
4. Etc.

I've searched for resources but haven't found one that fits all these criteria. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't cover statistics and probability, but [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1098125975) book does a great intro job of covering many of the basic problems of machine learning and real-world exercises in scikit-learn and tensorflow. There is a github [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3) that is regularly updated.